# Datatable formater

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I'm using datatable, I want to modify the content of a tr before it is generated.

return example:

```
      [0] => Array
            (
                [table] => atualizar
                [conn] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [table] => nas
                [conn] => 3
            )
```

My line must contain an attr with the value of conn and the description must be table!
I tried to use the events, fnRowCallback, createdRow, but I was not successful

[image]

Comment: 'createdRow': function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
                     $(row).attr('conn', data.conn);
                 },